# How is this moving mouth effect done?

Tags: paper

I'm not very skilled with paper. I'm a video editor looking to achieve [this effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zls4Ao3GyM).

[image: Mouth]

I'm well aware that most of it is special effects, and things like articulation are made of wire attached to the hands and arms of the character. Although, the mouth is make by practical effects. Could some good soul give to me a way to create a similar effect?

Comment: Are you looking to make a puppet of sorts? When you can pull or push "something" that makes the jaw move up and down to simulate speech? Is  the solution you are looking for only paper based? What do you plan to do with this knowledge? Your end result would influence your answers.

Comment: I also made some edits. Mostly a little spelling and reformed the title. I also added a new tag for `puppetry` figuring what I think you are doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to make it, I'd do something like this: 
[image: Puppet with moving jaw]

The face has to go on one piece of paper/cardboard, and the lower jaw is a separate piece. The strip of paper that is attached to the lower jaw, will go through the hole just below the face, so you can hold the strip and move it up and down without your hand being visible.
A large chin can cover the hole, when the mouth is closed. When the mouth is opened, you'll see a part of the hole.